# how to preload assets so that they don't shift when inserted to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

on this [live preview](https://aybak3k.github.io/wolves-fc/wolves-club/10.html) at the bottom of the page where is the select list "fav sport" the background changes according to the sport selected but the background takes time to load which causes a white color to show up for some time
How can I preload images so that white color-shifting doesn't appear
here's the file [link](https://github.com/Aybak3k/wolves-fc/blob/main/wolves-club/10.html) in the repo
PS: I'm really sorry for how poorly the code was written but it was back then when I was still seeing if programming is for me or not
feel free to include the script, styles in the markup file so that you don't get a headache by the project bad structure
I'd be really thankful for anyone helping, thx in advance

Comment: Can you please post your code here?

Comment: posting my code here will kinda spam it as the code is too long _in addition to_ it's not much of help as I'm just asking for a way to preload images<br>

Ofc I tried googling 1st but I didn't find what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For newer browser you could use

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="YOUR_IMAGE.jpg" />
```

Comment: thank you I'll try it asap

Comment: ok, that works but how to actually export it to CSS background use??